# In R, how to get the input variable name

Tags: r, variables

Code below.

> ```
>   func <- function(x){ 
> print( paste(substitute(x)) )
>  } ; 
> func(x[])
> ```

If I run func(x), the code print "x" out, but if I run like func(x[]) or func(x$y), it cannot print "x[]" or "x$y" out correctly. How can I get the correct input string? Thank you.

Similar example is like plot() function, when I use plot(x$y), the ylab is "x$y". When I use plot(x[]), the ylab is "x[]". When I use plot(1:20), the ylab is "1:20".

Comment: `print(deparse(substitute(x)))` see details section of `?substitute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `deparse` as well.

```
func <- function(x){
    deparse(substitute(x))
}
```

which gives

```
> func(x[1])
[1] "x[1]"
> func(x[])
[1] "x[]"
```